# Getting my edit suggestion processed

Tags: discussion, answers, suggested-edits

In regards to [this answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/18828/21587), it's been almost a week and my edit suggestion has not been approved or rejected.  Is something broken that it's not going through the review queues?  Is there some reason not to process it?

It's a pretty simple edit.  The original text had the names of two of the five players wrong.  One was a simple misspelling and the other was just wrong (unless a nickname?).  This is called out directly in a comment.  I fixed the two player names, made a note on one (he was not on the Celtics when he was on the All-Star team but he was the next season), and added reference links.  The edit seems clearly (to me) to simply correct and expand previous supporting information.  It's still the same answer (yes, this happened previously:  1975-6 Boston Celtics).

I don't think it makes sense to wait for the original poster decide, as that person hasn't posted since 2018.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that I didn't notice it in the queue... I don't think the site is showing me when there's edits in the queue in the tooltip (normally it would show on the menu).  Will try to check a bit more frequently!  But do please feel free to post like this if you have similar circumstances - we're just such a small site that it can go a while.

Comment: Longest time between edit suggestion and approval: [tag-wikis](https://data.stackexchange.com/sports/query/942650/longest-time-between-edit-suggestion-and-approval-only-tag-info?num=100), [posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/sports/query/942645/longest-time-between-edit-suggestion-and-approval-only-posts?num=100). And [tag-wikis on meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.sports/query/942650/longest-time-between-edit-suggestion-and-approval-only-tag-info?num=100).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally an edit requires

- two people to approve or to reject, or
- the original poster or a single moderator to make a decision

The edit had one approval vote at the time of writing. In lieu of waiting for someone else to check the review queue, I have approved the edit.

I think it would have been better posted separately, so I earlier chose not to approve or reject, but give the community a chance to decide either way (since the original answer was right in result but totally wrong in reasoning).